# "no javascript" error when trying to scrape web page

Tags: java

```
public class SearchWalm {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("https://www.walmart.ca/en/electronics/N-32+103/page-13?sortBy=newest&orderBy=DESC"))
                .GET()
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request,
                HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());

        System.out.println(response.body());
    }
}
```

I'm trying to write a program that will sift through pages on the walmart clearance section then select a keyword and tell me what page it found the keyword on.

I'm getting the error "no javascript" and "your web browser is not running javascript". Do I need to run this through a browser or is there a Java only way of doing this?

Comment: It's likely that the website is rendered on the client side using Javascript. You can verify it by loading the page in your browser with JS disabled. The server only serves a dummy blank page that loads the JS to render the page. In order to be able to scrape client rendered web pages, you will need to use a headless browser. It is like a regular browser (often without a visible window) controlled by your program. So when the dummy page loads, the browser is able to render the actual page using the loaded JS.

Answer (score 1):

Headless browser can solve scraping problems but unfortunately, your website loads content on-demand using javascript. To scrape on-demand data load, need an actual browser.

We use [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) and [Selenium WebDeiver](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/waits/) to solve this problem. Selenium WebDriver can allow Implicitly Wait(you set a timer) or Fluent Wait. Using this wait, we will wait until desired data loaded completely. After receiving we content, you parse data using jsoup and find out your desired result.

You also need Chrome/Firefox browser installed in your machine and need ChromeDriver/FirefoxDriver.

- Mac users with Homebrew installed: brew tap homebrew/cask && brew cask install chromedriver
- Debian based Linux distros: sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
- Windows users with Chocolatey installed: choco install chromedriver

Now you run the below code, which can search and show title from the search result.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


public class WebScraperJsOnload {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        String queryString = "https://www.walmart.ca/en/electronics/N-32+103/page-13?sortBy=newest&orderBy=DESC";
        
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(queryString);
        
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(driver.getPageSource());
        
        Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select(".title");
        for (Element headline : newsHeadlines) {
            log("Log: %s",headline.html());
        }
        
    }

    private static void log(String msg, String... vals) {
        System.out.println(String.format(msg, vals));
    }
}
```

Maven dependencies for this imports,

```
<dependency>
    <!-- jsoup HTML parser library @ https://jsoup.org/ -->
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.13.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

This code output looks like,

```
Log: <h2 class="thumb-header">Clearance Sale DR-E15 Fake Battery DC Coupler Battery Holder Mount Plate Power Supply Set Black</h2>
Log: <h2 class="thumb-header">Clearance Sale 2 in 1 4.7 inch Wireless U Disk Memory Expansion Phone Case for iPhone 6/6S/7 Red</h2>
Log: <h2 class="thumb-header">Clearance Sale USB Charging Power LED Selfie Ring Filling Light With Mobile Phone Clip Holder Black</h2>
Log: <h2 class="thumb-header">Clearance Sale Nillkin Protective Cover Plastic Hard Back Case Protect Mobile Phone Shell Red</h2>
Log: <h2 class="thumb-header">Clearance Sale Children'S Alarm Clock Creative Cute Cartoon Luminous Led Electronic Clock Pink</h2>
...
...
```

For the complete project, download this [Github Repo](https://github.com/khabib97/StackOverflow-Responses/tree/main/WebScrapingJsOnloading)

Comment: Is this solution helpful/solve your problem?

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda a java thing. You send different set of headers when doing request inside Java. I tried that url and works ok when you attach "Accept: */*" header.

You can't do it with your current implementation, reimplement it with [HttpClient](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html) and add the missing header.

Comment: thanks, I dont know headers i switched to HttpClient. how would i add a header to my code (i updated it in the question)

Comment: Add `.header("Accept", "*/*")` to the chain after your builder.

Comment: im still getting <p>JavaScript is required to view the Walmart Canada website. my code is ``` HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(URI.create("https://www.walmart.ca/en/electronics/N-32+103/page-13?sortBy=newest&orderBy=DESC"))
                    .headers("Accept", "*/*")
                    .GET()
                    .build();```

Comment: That's weird, I get now the proper content every time. Try also `.header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:85.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/85.0")`.

Comment: both still did nothing. i did notice i was using .headers instead of .header but that still didnt fix the issue

Comment: Apparently it relies on Cookie header. It's going to be a bit tricky. Add CookieManager to your HttpClient and make a few request to fill the cookie storage. For me I needed to make three request before I get the website.

Comment: `HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
        .cookieHandler(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL))
        .build();`

Comment: thanks, i added cookiemanager to my client, what do u mean by 3 requests did you run it 3 times or do u use httprequest 3 times. thank you all for all this help!

Comment: Walmart does a weird thing. It shows this message when there are no cookies set. In a browser it's only visible as a white page visible only for a moment. So you need to do a couple of requests on the same http client, so it's cookie store will populated.